# Select element before it css issue

Tags: css, focus, selector

I need to select the paragraph before the read more so that I can expand the height to the full height of the paragraph. I don't know how I can select it with the :focus selector

```css
.main {
  background: red;
}

button:focus **select the one div** {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one"><p>This is a paragraph. Extra words, Bla Bla........</P></div>
  <button>Read More<button>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Sibling combinator works only like this. From top to bottom tag

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
   <button>Read More</button>
   <div class="one">some</div>
</div>

<style>
.main {
background: red;
}

button:hover + .one {
background: pink;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the `:has()` pseudo-class but beware it's currently **not supported** by all browsers (especially not Firefox)

```
.main:has(button:focus) .one>p {
   height:auto;
}
```

Fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/6me19dLy/

"Can I use" report : https://caniuse.com/css-has